# Python requests library and dynamic-data

Tags: python, http-headers, python-requests, dynamic-data

I am using python’s requests library to get html code from some website (script, that allows check the accunt balance – mobile operator).
Script try to login into webpage and after validation, receiving the source code of one of subpages. On this subage, script trying to find some values, and after this, printing this values. All functions are executed in the same http session.

Unfortunatelly, always in first run, after some time from last executing (~30 min.), this values are not found.
In second run, there is no problem (and every next run) – if this code is executed enough often.
I checked the source code of subpage, when values are into it, and when values aren't into it.
Could you please tell me, how to use requests library with this type of data?
What I can do, to receive this values in every execution of script?

On diffchecker I upoloaded both html sources https://www.diffchecker.com/dn7ziRjJ

Headers are properly configured IMO:

```
self.myheaders = requests.utils.default_headers()
    self.myheaders.update(
        {
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0',
        }
    )
    self.s = requests.Session()
```

Comment: Maybe this has nothing to do with your code but how the server processes the request. Perhaps for the first time it handles the request slightly different (thus subsequent requests are slight different but consistently so)?

Comment: Thank you for response concerning to my problem. When I use web browser, there is no problem; no matter when and what I use - via web browser I receiving all data what I need.

Comment: Using a web browser is different from using requests (headless browser). The page might be getting extra information via AJAX requests.

Comment: Exactly. I need solution for this.

Comment: You could try and replace `requests` with [selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)

Comment: Solved, I called ajax request. This was so simple, only I needed only to search and read more than I thought at the beginning :)